# Google Secret Manager doesn't have access to GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, permission-denied, google-secret-manager

I've successfully created a GKE and deployed my service on it following [these](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/deploy-app-cluster#dockerfile) steps. Later I implemented [Google Secret Manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) in the service and redeployed it, but now I get this error message when I make a call: `Reading key and secret failed: failed to get key: rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Permission 'secretmanager.versions.access' denied for resource 'projects/*/secrets/*/versions/latest' (or it may not exist).`

I gave the `Secret Manager Admin` Permission to ***-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com (Compute Engine default service account), but I still get the same error message.

Did I forgot a last step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the Basic IAM roles pertaining to secret manager:

- Secret Manager Viewer - Enables listing of secrets.
- Secret Manager Secret Accessor - Enables access to secrets.
- Secret Manager Admin - Full access to administer Secret Manager resources.

Error is related to your service account not having access to the secrets you created, as you have mentioned you have already added `Secret Manager Admin` which may not be enough for accessing secrets. So try adding [Secret Manager Secret Accessor](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/access-control#secretmanager.secretAccessor) to the service account and let me know if you are facing errors.

Comment: Nope. I've added these roles and I still get the same error message.

Comment: Have you [configured your applications to authenticate to Google Cloud using Workload Identity.](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#authenticating_to)

Comment: Can you cross check if the service and deployment is using the default service account.

Comment: Problem solved! I've configured the Workload Identity and now everything's working fine. Thx!